# Java incompatible type: T cannot be converted to My Class

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

I am trying to write a custom comparator method to compare different things in my custom class Customer and when I compile I get `incompatible types: T cannot be converted to Customer`. DataChecker.compare() is run from a generic method but I know that whenever it is run T will be a type that is defined in the overloaded DataChecker.compare() method. Below is my code:

```
public int compare(Customer cust1, Customer cust2, String sortBy){ //Comparator interface for customers
    if (sortBy == "ID"){
            if (cust1.getID() < cust2.getID()){
                    return -1;
            } else if (cust1.getID() == cust2.getID()){
                    return 0;
            } else {
                    return 1;
            }
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a valid compare for Customer: " + sortBy);
}
```

The method is called here (left and right are T[ ] but when this is run T will be one of the types - e.g. Customer - that is defined in DataChecker.compare()):

```
if (DataChecker.compare(left[i], right[j], sortBy) <= 0){
        input[k++] = left[i++];
} else {
        input[k++] = right[j++];
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Type generics are erased at runtime, so `T` just becomes `Object`.  *You* know that `left` and `right` are both instances of `Customer`, but the *compiler* doesn't know that.  You have to tell it by using an explicit cast.  Just use `(Customer) left[i]` and `(Customer) right[j]` and you'll be all set.

Comment: Yes that would work but it won't always be `(Customer) left[i]` as there will be other types that use the same method

Comment: Try using the type `<T extends Comparable<T>>` in the type def instead

Comment: @Bohemian I've tried this but I don't think I've done it correctly. I can't find anything on the internet that properly explains comparators with generics. Would you be able to explain what you mean in more detail?

Comment: You have to check what type it is with `instanceof` then.  The compiler doesn't know which method overload you want to call, you have to tell it that through the explicit cast.  Imagine if you had two overloads: one that accepted `Customer`s, and one that accepted `Object`s.  An instance of `Customer` could be passed to either method overload in this case.  Which one does the compiler choose?  It chooses based on the type you specified.  So you need to explicitly declare which type that argument is.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong `instanceof` worked for me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> T will be a type that is defined in the overloaded DataChecker.compare() method.

That is almost entirely useless. In java, overloads are **completely different methods** that have absolutely no relationship whatsoever; code is interpreted at compile (write) time to one of the overloads, and that particular method is then hardcoded in your class file. At runtime, **override** is applied dynamically (java is fully dynamically dispatched), but the 'full name' of each method includes the complete type it is, the name, and the types of each parameter, and the return type.

In other words, it is *not possible* to tell the compiler: Just figure it out; call the right `compare` method, and I guarantee you it will be there. I guess, if not, throw a ClassCastException or something.

If you think about it for a while, this starts to make some sense. `String` is a subtype of `Object`, but also of `CharSequence`, and also of `Serializable`. Imagine you had `compare(Serializable a, Serializable b)` as well as `compare(CharSequence a, CharSequence b)`. Which one should be called?

The only solution, then, is to either have no overloads, or to create a single method that is the entrypoint for this dynamic process, which does its own, handrolled dynamic dispatch, based on e.g. a `Map<Class<?>, BiPredicate<?>>` or a bunch of `instanceof` checks.